# Replace a Fragment created from Navigation Drawer with another dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer that works well. By well I mean I can navigate through all the fragments tied to the Navigation drawer (A,B,C,D).  My issue arises here. Lets say am in Fragment A, in this fragment I have a button which on clicking should ideally replace the fragment with another one say Frag Z, and once I am in Frag Z I can return back to frag A.

To achieve this I use the below code. However the new fragment Z appears transparent on top of Fragment A. What could be the problem:

```
                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                 bundle.putInt("int", 1);
                 bundle.putString("str","string" ); 
                 fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 FragZ fragmentz = new FragZ();
                 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.some_container, fragmentz);
                 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**EDIT:**

I have found a workaround to this as shown below,however it does not completely solve my problem since the newly displayed fragment is still shown with the navigation drawer capable of being toggled,but it atleast removed the overlaying of the fragments. I would still want a solution to launching an independent fragment

```
                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                 bundle.putInt("int", 1);
                 bundle.putString("str","string" ); 
                 FragZ fragmentz = new FragZ();
                 FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                 ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment);
                 ft.addToBackStack(null);
                 ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your activity to launch fragments. Whenever you want to display the fragment, just call in with a number or string to represent the fragment. You can use the same function to launch fragments from your navigation drawer.

For example:

```
public void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    currentFragmentNumber = position;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        fragment = new frag1();

        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new frag2();

        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new frag3();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack("tag").commit();            

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

You can call this function from your activity by using:

```
((**ActivityName**) getActivity()).displayView(0);
```

Comment: This would work on any Fragment Activity pair...however my scenario is unique because of the added Navigation Drawer. In your case I will just be replacing subsequent fragments in the frame layout (R.id.frame_container) which is exactly what I edited my question to show I can achieve but is not what am looking for, I want a situation where a newly created fragment does not reside in the nav drawer